# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate contain sqlexpress?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2012-r2

I just installed VS 2013 ultimate in Windows Server 2012 R2 but not able to find sqlexpress. I checked in services as well as Sql Server Configuration Manager but couldn't find one with sqlexpress. May I know where I can find it? Should I start it somehow? Note that I'm able to open the database using (LocalDb)\v11.0 through sql management studio but not able to ensure the service is running.

Comment: I believe this should be asked on Server Fault.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have SQL Server installed already....Perhaps VS skips installing SQL Express if you have full blown SQL Server installed.  (Usually SQL Express is normal SQL with some limitations...Unless I misunderstand you somehow).  Can you see your databases in Management Studio?  Can you connect to your server?  If so, check the Properties of the SQL Server...it may indeed be SQL Server (Express)

Otherwise have you checked the install material for the SQL Express installation? Perhaps you can run that manually.